# Wireless mouse periodically stutter/freeze after a certain time of inactivity (of the mouse)

Tags: linux, mouse, wireless-mouse

Update 4: As it turned out, only the old one has the behavior, so it is not a general issue. Maybe we will never know the reason of that.

---

Update 3: (also see the Arch bbs post) It seems that the issue is with the mouse alone (and possibly this particular mouse). Since this issue appears in both Raspberry Pi OS and Windows. I have requested a new one from the retailer and will update the question later.

---

**Update 2:** I am starting to think this is not a sleep-mode issue (see the bold text below). I have put the mouse idle for 10 minutes, and it went into a mode I have to wake up with a button click. That might be the actual sleep mode. (or are there two, a deep one and a normal one?)

---

Update 1: I posted the same question on Arch bbs: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=270149, see the discussion there as well.

---

I am using Arch Linux and a wireless mouse, in this case, an Inphic PM6 wireless mouse, on a laptop.

**The behavior**:

After a certain time (exact 60 seconds for the current mouse) of inactivity, if I move the mouse again, the cursor will freeze for ~100 milliseconds (most of the time around 120 ms) for every 383.8 milliseconds.

At the later part of the post, I will explain what I have done to analysis the behavior and how I got the exact period of 383.8 milliseconds.

**A workaround**:

Switch the mouse off and on again (why not :)) will temporarily make the mouse work well, but issue still appear after the same time of inactivity.

**The question**:

Has anyone had the same issue? How to make the periodic, short freeze go away?

======

What is (not) related / What I have (not) tried:

- I think the stutter (I am not sure if this is the right word, I am not a native speaker) is mostly related to the mouse's **sleep feature for power-saving**. Most wireless mouse has this feature.

  I have once played a game non-stop for more than one hour, and there was no issue. I infer that's since the mouse has not turned into sleep mode.
- This is probably not related to software taking up CPU, or any particular software blocking the mouse. The issue occurs even when my computer is idling.
- I had this issue for other wireless mice, only I didn't dig into and do the analysis to them as below. I will look into those and update this post later.
- I haven't tried other operating systems or computer hardware. I have another Arch Linux desktop and a Raspberry Pi 4B with Raspberry Pi OS. I will try on those machines later, too.
- I haven't tried changing drivers or similar low-level software. This is because I am not familiar with this stuff, I don't know where to start.

======

Since I am a grad-student in science, I used my skill to analysis the results I get from `xev' command. These are the steps:

1. I run the following command, and move the mouse in circles inside the `xev' window (the point is moving the mouse non-stop) to get the time sequence of the mouse events:

   ```sh
   xev | grep root | sed 's/.*time \([0-9]*\).*/\1/p' > data.txt
   ```
2. I used the following python code to plot the time span between two mouse events against time:

   ```python
   import numpy
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   data = numpy.loadtxt('data.txt')
   t = data - data[0]
   difft = t[1:] - t[:-1]
   plt.plot(t[1:], difft, lw=0.5)
   ```
3. I get the following image:

   [screenshot of `xev' result analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9lrG.png)

Interpretation:

If the data points are large in the figure, that means there was a time span where the mouse didn't move at all (freeze), and the height means the length of that freeze time. The length between two freeze point is the period of the freezing.

So If you open the image link, you will see the mouse freeze for 110~120 milliseconds with an almost perfect period. I measured (in plt.show(), where I can get more accurate coordinates) that period to be exact 383.8 to 383.9 milliseconds, every time.

Comment: This is probably part of the mouse firmware to save the battery and there is probably nothing you can do about it.  I hope someone comes along and provides better information than I.  I have a Jelly Comb mouse that does this.  I have to switch it off, then on to get it to work again.  For troubleshooting, plug it into a different OS (windows,macos) and see if the behavior follows the mouse or the OS (I bet you will find that it is the mouse firmware).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas thanks for commenting. I have been trying to find a Windows machine and test my mouse there (I don't have one of my own). I also have some other wireless mice that I can test, some of those have similar behavior. Actually I do hope it's a firmware issue, since if so other mice would work well.

Comment: @LuXu, I suspect you'll find more or less the same behaviour with all mice. After some period of inactivity it'll turn off/go to sleep, and take some prodding (and time) to wake up. My Bluetooth mice just disconnect and you have to wait a bit for them to reconnect. My (now unused) wireless mice also went to sleep, but woke up/reconnected faster.

Comment: @vonbrand, you and SeñorCMasMas are both right, thanks! I just tried different mice with different OSes, and it turned out that only this particular mouse has this issue everywhere, even on Windows. I wrongly assumed that a wireless mouse will work on Windows and didn't check that out in the first place. Then every conclusion after is based on a wrong assumption that the issue is not due to the mouse only. Now I will try updating the firmware or request a refund. I guess I will answer myself after I deal with this completely.

Comment: I updated the final result. But I am not sure if "it is only with that one mouse" could be used as an answer. Or does the answer need to be the actual reason why it happened for that exact mouse (and leave it unsolved if we never know)?

Comment: I have the same issue with a Logitech M185 wireless mouse. However the freeze is not ~100ms long but several seconds (3-4) where I can't move or click.